# Session has timed out or your "SessionId" parameter is invalid using Regular expression extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Im using JMeter for my testing.I am successful extract the session id value from previous request using regular expression extractor but it failed in testing pls see the image

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You changed session ID in the URL but left hard-coded (recorded?) value in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler parameters

   [image: JMeter Correlation]
2. Double check this `${SessionId}` variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination, it might be the case your Regular Expression Extractor configuration is wrong.